# For positive intergers m an n, let $F_n=2^{2^n}+1$ and $G_m=2^{2^n}-1$. Which of the following statements are true?

Tags: number-theory

For positive intergers m an n, let $F_n=2^{2^n}+1$ and $G_m=2^{2^m}-1$. Which of the following statements are true?

1. $F_n$ divides $G_m$ whenever $m>n$.
2. $GCD(F_n,G_m)=1$ whenever $m\neq n$
3. $GCD(F_n,F_m)=1$ whenever $m\neq n$
4. $G_m$ divides $F_n$ whenever $m<n$.

Comment: Not to nitpick, but shouldn't $G_m$ be $2^{2^m}-1$

Comment: @tpb261 ya its m.. sorry typo

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:** Note that if $m\lt n$, then $2^{2^n}=(2^{2^m})^{2^{n-m}}$.

$1$) is true. This is essentially because $x+1$ and $x-1$ divide $x^2-1$.

$2$) Look at $1$).

$3$) Suppose $m\lt n$, and $p$ is a prime common divisor. Then $2^{2^m}\equiv -1\pmod p$. Since $2^{2^n}$ is obtained from $2^{2^m}$ by repeated squaring, we have $2^{2^n}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$.

$4$) Note that $G_m$ divides $G_n$. That implies it cannot divide $F_n$.